# How the browser knows that this is a jQuery event object and not a normal event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

jQuery event object has some attributes and methods written in the jQuery library, I wonder how does the browser know that we are using a jQuery event object and not a normal event, because I notice we don't make any extra work that shows that!

Answer (score 2):

Your event handler never gets bound to the element. Instead it sits in the entry to `window.jQuery.cache` that is associated with the element.

What does get bound is a generic event handler. When an event occurs, that handler grabs the browser's event object, sees what type of event it was, looks up your handler in `jQuery.cache`, and invokes it.

But before invoking it, it makes a new event object to pass to your handler instead of the original *(though it includes the original)*.

Answer (score 1):

The browser doesn't know... jQuery captures the event, gets the normal event object and normalize it.

> jQuery’s event system normalizes the event object according to W3C standards. The event object is guaranteed to be passed to the event handler. Most properties from the original event are copied over and normalized to the new event object.

[Docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

Comment: I hope this is what you're asking of course, as it's not that clear.

Comment: jquery parses javascript code to extract events and normalize them, is this what do you want to say !

Comment: @user2080105, I have no idea what you just wrote. Sorry. :)